# Pip install logging getting: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python

I am trying to install "logging" package using pip on python3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04. But getting the error below. However, this package also is not shown with pip list, but can be imported via python console as though it was already installed, but hidden?  Please advise how to fix this error and make it show up on pip list command.

```py
  User install by explicit request
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-b4xjtmdo
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-ihsjvua2
  Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-ihsjvua2
  Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-ihsjvua2
  Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-ihsjvua2
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-7om0f202
  Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://piwheels.org/simple
  2 location(s) to search for versions of logging:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/logging/
  * https://piwheels.org/simple/logging/
  Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/logging/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/logging/
  Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
  Getting credentials from keyring for https://pypi.org/simple
  Getting credentials from keyring for pypi.org
  Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/logging/" in the cache
  Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
  https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/logging/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0
    Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/4b/979db9e44be09f71e85c9c8cfc42f258adfb7d93ce01deed2788b2948919/logging-0.4.9.6.tar.gz#sha256=26f6b50773f085042d301085bd1bf5d9f3735704db9f37c1ce6d8b85c38f2417 (from https://pypi.org/simple/logging/), version: 0.4.9.6
  Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://piwheels.org/simple/logging/
  Getting page https://piwheels.org/simple/logging/
  Found index url https://piwheels.org/simple
  Getting credentials from keyring for https://piwheels.org/simple
  Getting credentials from keyring for piwheels.org
  Looking up "https://piwheels.org/simple/logging/" in the cache
  Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): piwheels.org:443
  https://piwheels.org:443 "GET /simple/logging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 107
  Updating cache with response from "https://piwheels.org/simple/logging/"
  Caching due to etag
  Given no hashes to check 1 links for project 'logging': discarding no candidates
  Using version 0.4.9.6 (newest of versions: 0.4.9.6)
  Collecting logging
    Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-unpack-2ylf_t2k
    Getting credentials from keyring for files.pythonhosted.org
    Looking up "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/4b/979db9e44be09f71e85c9c8cfc42f258adfb7d93ce01deed2788b2948919/logging-0.4.9.6.tar.gz" in the cache
    Current age based on date: 11226
    Ignoring unknown cache-control directive: immutable
    Freshness lifetime from max-age: 365000000
    The response is "fresh", returning cached response
    365000000 > 11226
    Using cached logging-0.4.9.6.tar.gz (96 kB)
    Added logging from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/4b/979db9e44be09f71e85c9c8cfc42f258adfb7d93ce01deed2788b2948919/logging-0.4.9.6.tar.gz#sha256=26f6b50773f085042d301085bd1bf5d9f3735704db9f37c1ce6d8b85c38f2417 to build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-ihsjvua2'
      Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-install-7om0f202/logging/setup.py) egg_info for package logging
      Running command python setup.py egg_info
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
          __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.specifiers')
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/specifiers.py", line 24, in <module>
          from .utils import canonicalize_version
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
          from .tags import Tag, parse_tag
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/tags.py", line 5, in <module>
          import logging
        File "/tmp/pip-install-7om0f202/logging/logging/__init__.py", line 618
          raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                   ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      Error in sys.excepthook:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
          from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
          from apport.report import Report
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
          import apport.fileutils
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 12, in <module>
          import os, glob, subprocess, os.path, time, pwd, sys, requests_unixsocket
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
          import requests
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
          import urllib3
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
          from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
          import logging
        File "/tmp/pip-install-7om0f202/logging/logging/__init__.py", line 618
          raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                   ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  
      Original exception was:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
          __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.specifiers')
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/specifiers.py", line 24, in <module>
          from .utils import canonicalize_version
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
          from .tags import Tag, parse_tag
        File "/home/lab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/tags.py", line 5, in <module>
          import logging
        File "/tmp/pip-install-7om0f202/logging/logging/__init__.py", line 618
          raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                   ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  Cleaning up...
    Removing source in /tmp/pip-install-7om0f202/logging
  Removed logging from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/4b/979db9e44be09f71e85c9c8cfc42f258adfb7d93ce01deed2788b2948919/logging-0.4.9.6.tar.gz#sha256=26f6b50773f085042d301085bd1bf5d9f3735704db9f37c1ce6d8b85c38f2417 from build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-ihsjvua2'
  Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-ihsjvua2'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Exception information:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 357, in run
      resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
      discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
      abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
      abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 515, in prepare_linked_requirement
      abstract_dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 95, in _get_prepared_distribution
      abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 40, in prepare_distribution_metadata
      self.req.prepare_metadata()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 564, in prepare_metadata
      self.metadata_directory = self._generate_metadata()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 538, in _generate_metadata
      return generate_metadata_legacy(
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/build/metadata_legacy.py", line 115, in generate_metadata
      call_subprocess(
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
      raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
  pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ``
```